# Change button text with user name using jQuery after user login

Tags: jquery, login

I have a button to link the login page at the top and after login I want the "Login" text of the button to be "Hi Username - Logout".
my link is :

```
<a class="btn mylogin" href="/profile/">Login</a>
```

Any help?
Thank you.

P.S. Working on the Wordpress 4.7.5

Comment: You can use is_user_logged_in() i.e. a WordPess function that can help you change the button text.  Doing with jQuery isnt a good idea.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code bellow:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

    <li> <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">Logout</a></li>

<?php else : ?>

    <li> <a href="http://your-site-name/login/">Login</a></li>

<?php endif;?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
       <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 ?>

            <li> <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">Logout</a></li>
    <li>Username:  <?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?></li>
        <?php else : ?>

            <li> <a href="http://your-site-name/login/">Login</a></li>

        <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Looks good but how can I have the user name also?

Comment: I enter the name like this: <?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
printf( __( '%s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_login ) );

?>, worked but is it ok with you, any comment?

Comment: Yes Sounds good....... I've updated my answer

Comment: well it must be inside <?php .... ?>, like this <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?> and works perfect!. Please update your post